# Unordered map storing object vs pointer (as value)

Tags: c++, hashmap

What would be a more efficient way for storing objects in the "std::unordered_map" when a lot of erasing and inserting operations will be  involved? I would like to minimize the unnecessary copies of **MyObject** and I'm worried that this might happen during IO operations.

```
struct MyObject { ... };
std::unordered_map<key, MyObject> mMyMap;
```

vs

```
struct MyObject { ... };
std::unordered_map<key, std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> mMyMap;
```

Comment: Proper use of move-semantics will all but ensure it won't happen regardless. Interestingly, you'll have to use them anyway to move that unique-ptr to the map and out from wherever it resided prior.